# Is it possible to build mobile apps using VSCode Dev Containers / GitHub Codespaces?

Tags: flutter, xamarin, vscode-devcontainer, github-codespaces

My assumption is no, due to the need for device connectivity or running emulators which exceeds the capabilities of Dev Containers and containers in general that seem to rely on opening ports to expose the running app.

There seems to be very little written about this subject however so would like to open up the question.

Does anyone have any experience trying to build apps with frameworks such as Flutter or Xamarin on VSCode Dev Containers / GitHub Codespaces, or using remote container development in general?

Comment: I don’t know about flutter, but instead of xamarin, consider .net maui. Might be able to adapt the winui 3 platform implementation. I would wait a few months before attempting - need more advanced docs and examples. Fundamentally, .net 6 itself and maui UI are attempting to be cleaner cross-platform foundations.

Comment: Or start with .net 6 only - no UI. As if you were writing tests for an app, so UI is all stubbed. Might also seek people running .net 6 under WebAssembly - similar concerns.

Comment: I wonder if opening the workspace in VSCode locally rather than the browser. For Flutter, the SDK is then installed plus the Flutter extension there locally. But the debugging - I doubt it will work with Codespaces port forwarding alone ...

Comment: You can run as web app,